# print all matches or replace all strings in a BIG file which is NOT line organised (no line separators)

Tags: text-processing

The 5GB files I have are streams of data rows formed:

```
    {datarow1...},{datarow2...},...,{datarowN...}
```

so actually could say that there are lines `{}`, and even line separators, but coming as a three char sequence: `},{`

I want to do two things:

1. print "`lines`" that have string `"error"` in it:

   ```
   grep -o -P {[^{}]+?error.+?} ES01.log > ES01.err.log
   ```
2. make the file more "friendly" by explicitly producing files with new line separators

   ```
   <ES01.log sed -e 's/},{/}\n{/g' > ESnl01.log
   ```

While the above works for relatively small files (up to ~100MB), my files are unfortunately a lot bigger therefore hitting the memory problems here:

```
    grep: memory exhausted
    sed: couldn't re-allocate memory
```

as both grep and sed try to read/process files line by line which in this case (no separators) leads to loading whole files into memory.

Any idea how to approach this using some another smart one-liner?

Answer (score 2):

With `gawk`:

```
gawk -v 'RS=},{' '{sub(",", "\n", RT); printf "%s", $0 RT}' < file
```

perl equivalent:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/="},{"}; s/\,{$/\n{/' < file
```

Otherwise, POSIXly:

```
tr , '\n' < file | awk '{
  if (/^{/ && e) print ""
  printf "%s", $0
  if (/}$/) e=1
  else {e=0; printf ","}}
  END {print ""}'
```

Pipe those to `grep error` to see the records with errors, and to `paste -sd, -` to restore to original format.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="},{"} chomp; 
          s/\n$//; s/^{//; s/}$//; 
          print "{$_}\n"; ' k
```

This is the same principle as the `gawk` one that StephaneChazelas suggested, in Perl, `$/` is the record separator, so we set that to `},{` to read the records correctly and then print them with newlines.

You could easily expand this to do both of the operations you ask for:

```
perl -i -ne 'BEGIN{$/="},{"}
             chomp; 
             s/\n$//; s/^{//; s/}$//; print "{$_}\n"; 
             print STDERR "{$_}\n" if /error/' file 2> ES01.err.log
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas ah, yes, so it does. Sod it then, I'll just leave the perl one.

Comment: Note that it adds an extra `{` to the first record and `}\n` to the last one.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas this one should work correctly but not really worth it anymore, too complex. Your awk is much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try a program that is probably not yet installed on your system, try `gsar`, explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137600/5923) to the same problem.

`gsar` is a search and (optionally) replace utility that operates on binary files.
It cannot however search with regular expressions.

This command:

```
gsar '-s},{' '-r}:x0A{' ES01.log > ESnl01.log
```

replaces the comma between `}{` with a newline character, reading from ES01.log and redirecting output to ESnl01.log.

The search (`-s`) and replacement (`-r`) strings do not be of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this simply through Perl using regex.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=}),(?=\{)/\n/g' file
```