# non-line-oriented tool for string replacement?

Tags: text-processing

I recently asked [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137391/5923) about how to remove the newline character if it occurs after another specific character.

Unix text-processing tools are very powerful, but almost all of them deal with lines of text, which is fine most of the time when the input fits in the available memory.

**But what should I do if I wish to replace a text sequence in a huge file that doesn't contain any newlines?**

For instance replace `<foobar>` with `\n<foobar>` without reading the input line-by-line? (since there is only one line and it is 2.5G characters long).

Comment: Are you open to using `perl` or `python`?

Comment: Perl is fine. I just found `gsar` (http://home.online.no/~tjaberg/) which I will try.

Comment: How can you read a file that has no newlines "line by line"?

Comment: it will be 1 line then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**gsar** [(general search and replace)](http://home.online.no/~tjaberg/) is a very useful tool for exactly this purpose.

Most answers to this question use record-based tools and various tricks to make them adapt to the problem, such as switching the default record separator character to something assumed to be occurring frequently enough in the input not to make each record too large to handle.

In many cases this is very fine and even readable. I do like problems that can be easily/efficiently solved with everywhere-available tools such as `awk`, `tr`, `sed` and the bourne shell.

Performing a binary search and replace in an arbitrary huge file with random contents does not fit very well for these standard unix tools.

Some of you may think this is cheating, but I don't see how using the right tool for the job can be wrong. In this case it is a C program called `gsar` that is licenced under **GPL v2**, so it surprises me quite a bit that there is no package for this very useful tool in neither *gentoo*, *redhat*, nor *ubuntu*.

`gsar` uses a binary variant of the [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Usage is straight-forward:

```
gsar -F '-s<foobar>' '-r:x0A<foobar>'
```

where `-F` means "filter" mode, ie read `stdin` write to `stdout`. There are methods to operate on files as well. `-s` specifies the search string and `-r` the replacement. The colon-notation can be used to specify arbitrary byte values.

Case-insensitive mode is supported (`-i`), but there is no support for regular expressions, since the algorithm uses the length of the search string to optimize the search.

The tool can also be used just for searching, a bit like `grep`. `gsar -b` outputs the byte offsets of the matched search string, and `gsar -l` prints filename and number of matches if any, a bit like combining `grep -l` with `wc`.

The tool was written by *Tormod Tjaberg* (initial) and *Hans Peter Verne* (improvements).

Comment: If it's GPL'd would you consider packaging it up for a distro :)

Comment: In fact I'm thinking rather seriously about making a gentoo ebuild for it. Maybe an rpm as well. But I have never build a .deb package before, so I hope someone beats me to it (because it will take me some time).

Comment: I doubt this is much consolation but OS X's homebrew has the formula for `gsar`.

Answer (score 12):

The first thing that occurs to me when facing this type of problem is to change the record separator. In most tools, this is set to `\n` by default but that can be changed. For example:

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -0x3E -pe 's/<foobar>/\n$&/' file
   ```

   #### Explanation

   - `-0` : this sets the input record separator to a character given its [hexadecimal value](http://www.asciitable.com/). In this case, I am setting it to `>` whose hex value is `3E`. The general format is `-0xHEX_VALUE`. This is just a trick to break the line into manageable chunks.
   - `-pe` : print each input line after applying the script given by `-e`.
   - `s/<foobar>/\n$&/` : a simple substitution. The `$&` is whatever was matched, in this case `<foobar>`.
2. awk

   ```
   awk '{gsub(/foobar>/,"\n<foobar>");printf "%s",$0};' RS="<" file
   ```

   #### Explanation

   - `RS="<"` : set the input record separator to `>`.
   - `gsub(/foobar>/,"\n<foobar>")` : substitute all cases of `foobar>` with `\n<foobar>`. Note that because `RS` has been set to `<`, all `<` are removed from the input file (that's how `awk` works) so we need to match `foobar>` (without a `<`) and replace with `\n<foobar>`.
   - `printf "%s",$0` : print the current "line" after the substitution. `$0` is the current record in `awk` so it will hold whatever was before the `<`.

I tested these on a 2.3 GB, single-line file created with these commands:

```
for i in {1..900000}; do printf "blah blah <foobar>blah blah"; done > file
for i in {1..100}; do cat file >> file1; done
mv file1 file
```

Both the `awk` and the `perl` used negligible amounts of memory.

Comment: Have you ever tried `Tie::File` http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html. I think it's best features of `Perl` when dealing with huge files.

Comment: @Gnouc I've played with it a little, yes. But i) the OP has already professed a dislike of Perl in another question so I wanted to keep it simple ii) I tend to avoid using external modules unless absolutely necessary and iii) Using the Tie::File module would make the syntax considerably less clear.

Comment: Agree. A little note that `Tie::File` is a core module since `v5.7.3`.

Answer (score 5):

In the narrow case where target and replacement strings are of the same length, [memory mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) can come to the rescue. This is especially useful if the replacement needs to be performed in-place. You're basically mapping a file into a process's virtual memory, and the address space for 64-bit addressing is huge. **Note that the file is not necessarily mapped into physical memory all at once**, so files that are several time the size of the physical memory available on the machine can be dealt with.

Here's a Python example that replaces `foobar` with `XXXXXX`

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import mmap
import contextlib   
with open('test.file', 'r+') as f:
 with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as m:
   pos = 0
   pos = m.find('foobar', pos)
   while pos > 0:
    m[pos: pos+len('XXXXXX')] = 'XXXXXX'
    pos = m.find('foobar', pos)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many tools for this:

`dd` is what you want to use if you want to block a file off - reliably read only a certain number of bytes only a certain number of times. It portably handles blocking and unblocking file streams:

`tr -dc '[:graph:]' </dev/urandom |
 dd bs=32 count=1 cbs=8 conv=unblock,sync 2>/dev/null`

```
###OUTPUT###
```

`UI(#Q5\e
 BKX2?A:Z
 RAxGm:qv
 t!;/v!)N`

I also use `tr` above because it can handle converting any ASCII byte to any other (or, in this case, deleting any ASCII byte that isn't a not-space printable character). It's what I used in [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137452/52934) to your other question this morning, in fact, when I did:

```
tr '>\n' '\n>' | sed 's/^>*//' | tr '\n>' '>\n'
```

There are [many similar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/xrat/port.html#tag_04_02_14). That list should provide a lowest common-denominator subset with which you might become familiar.

But, if I were going to do text processing on 2.5gbs of binary file, I might start with `od`. It can give you an `octal dump` or any of several other formats. You can specify all kinds of options - but I'll just do one byte per line in a `\C` escaped format:

The data you'll get from `od` will be regular at whatever interval you specify - as I show below. But first - here's an answer to your question:

```
printf 'first\nnewline\ttab spacefoobar\0null' |
od -A n -t c -v -w1 |
sed 's/^ \{1,3\}//;s/\\$/&&/;/ /bd
     /\\[0nt]/!{H;$!d};{:d
    x;s/\n//g}'
```

That little bit above delimits on `\n`ewlines, `\0`nulls, `\t`abs and `<spaces>` while preserving the `\C` escaped string for the delimiter. Note the `H` and `x` functions used - every time `sed` encounters a delimiter it swaps out the contents of its memory buffers. In this way `sed` only retains as much information as it must to reliably delimit the file and does not succumb to buffer overruns - does not, that is, so long as it actually encounters its delimiters. For so long as it does, `sed` will continue to process its input and `od` will continue to provide it until it encounters `EOF`.

As is, its output looks like this:

```
first
\nnewline
\ttab
 spacefoobar
\0null
```

So if I want `foobar`:

```
printf ... | od ... | sed ... | 
sed 's/foobar/\
&\
/g'

###OUTPUT###

first
\nnewline
\ttab
 space
foobar

\0null
```

Now if you want to make use of the `C` escapes it's pretty easy - because `sed` has already double `\\`backslash escaped all of its single input backslashes, so `printf` execed from `xargs` will have no issues producing the output to your specification. But `xargs` *eats shell quotes* so you'll need to double quote it again:

```
printf 'nl\ntab\tspace foobarfoobar\0null' |
PIPELINE |
sed 's/./\\&/g' | 
xargs printf %b | 
cat -A

###OUTPUT###

nl$
tab^Ispace $
foobar$
$
foobar$
^@null%
```

That could have as easily been saved to a shell variable and output later in identical fashion. The last `sed` inserts a `\`backslash before every character in its input, and that's all.

And here's what it all looks like before ever `sed` gets hold of it:

```
printf 'nl\ntab\tspace foobarfoobar\0null' |
od -A n -t c -v -w1

   n
   l
  \n
   t
   a
   b
  \t
   s
   p
   a
   c
   e

   f
   o
   o
   b
   a
   r
   f
   o
   o
   b
   a
   r
  \0
   n
   u
   l
   l
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk operates on successive records. It can use any character as the record separator (except the null byte on many implementations). Some implementations support arbitrary regular expressions (not matching the empty string) as the record separator, but this can be unwieldy because the record separator is truncated from the end of each record before it is stowed into `$0` (GNU awk sets the variable `RT` to the record separator that was stripped from the end of the current record). Note that `print` terminates its output with the output record separator `ORS` which is a newline by default and set independently from the input record separator `RS`.

```
awk -v RS=, 'NR==1 {printf "input up to the first comma: %s\n", $0}'
```

You can effectively select a different character as the record separator for other tools (`sort`, `sed`, …) by swapping newlines with that character with `tr`.

```
tr '\n,' ',\n' |
sed 's/foo/bar/' |
sort |
tr '\n,' ',\n'
```

Many GNU text utilities support using a null byte instead of a newline as the separator.